# Same property defined in multiple active profiles in maven - which one shall win?

Tags: maven

What exactly would happen when multiple profiles are activated and they have conflicting definitions of a properties?  For example, if there are two profiles both define the properties `${platform-path}` but define it as two different values, what would be the final effective value used?

I tried using the `help:effective-pom` and it seems it is the profile defined later in the `settings.xml` file who has the last word, but I could not seem to see this behavior documented in either the maven site nor the sonaType book.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it depends on the implementation of the xml parser.
A quick test showed me that the last definition of the variable on the pom file is the one that is considered the correct one.